# Create your own Cascade File

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have started to study object detection with Python-OpenCV. I want to create my own cascade files. Is there any software that will do it instead of me? For example, I can just give the positive and the negative images and then it gives me a cascade.xml file as output to train.